kubuntu 22.04 + nginx + apache2 + php = 'service apache2 restart' regularly necessary
kubuntu 22.04 + nginx + apache2 + php = 'service apache2 restart' regularly necessary.
i've already set a TimeOut value of 20 in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, but not even that is getting used.. :(
EDIT : i was told to include the results of a 'free' command;
root@parakeet:~# free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        65557616     6486344    23064976      222368    36006296    58175612
Swap:        2097148           0     2097148


Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour]. As originally written,  it's hard to determine what you're asking,  much less what to suggest. For instance, how much RAM/swap space do you have? The free command will tell you. [Edit] your Question to add information.  Do not use Add Comment.

with all due respect, i'll need a short list of commands or some kind of generic Linux commandline sudo script to fetch you people the OS details that you request. and i'd like a way to filter out which categories of system settings make it to output, please :)

i've had an opportunity to test the output of the 'free' command while the freeze of apache2 is happening, and there is no difference in the output. i got plenty of free RAM.

You didn't follow my instructions: did not show us the output of free, AND replied via Add Comment.  I won't help you anymore.

"do not use add coment" - in your first comment.

*/1 * * * * service apache2 restart && service nginx restart

added to 'crontab -e' on the commandline, seems to do the trick for me :)
i also raised the apache2 and nginx concurrent connections option (an int).
